# Pushing data to firebase with python not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to push my code to firebase from my raspberry pi. Basically I am doing a project that sends information to a database on whether or not a plant is dry.

The code I have is follows,it successfully posts the information to firebase, but without making any children, it just posts it as one long piece of information.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time 
import glob 
import urllib2
import datetime
import json
import calendar
from firebase import firebase


firebase = firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://monitoringapp-c5c2a.firebaseio.com/moisture')

def read_moisture(channel):  
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        print "20% Remaining"
        date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
        moisture = 'Plants Dry'
        data = {'moisture': moisture, 'time': date}
        sent = json.dumps(data)
        result = firebase.post('/moisture', sent)
    else:
        print "Plants watered" 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
channel = 17
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.BOTH, bouncetime=300)
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, read_moisture)



while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MK4g.png)

[This is how I had hoped it would turn out, this layout but not with a user node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvJqv.png)

I have also tried using

```
data = {"moisture": moisture, "date": date}
db.child("moisture").push(data)
```

However it is giving more errors. 
Any help would be excellent as this is my first time using firebase, and python is also new to me.

Comment: Hey Peter, it was a mistake, I was just hoping to have that layout and didnt know the right words to say it. I am just looking a "moisture" node and yes, i have tried creating this with a moisture node by trying 
"data = {"moisture": moisture, "date": date}
db.child("moisture").push(data)"

Comment: yeah and i have the code pushing to my firebase database just fine, it is just not sorting itself into different attributes, just all as one line

Comment: do this: `data={"email" : youremail, "name":yourname, "phone_num":phonenumber} db.child("users").push(data);`

Comment: When I do that, i get AttributeError: 'FirebaseApplication' object has no attribute 'child'

Comment: it is the moisture method I am trying to push, not the users details, the user table was only an example. so I tried to enter "  data = {"moisture": moisture, "time": date}
sent = json.dumps(data)
db.child("moisture").push(data);